# How do I use a JavaScript object as an aura:attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

How do I use a JavaScript object as an aura:attribute?

Should I do it this way
`<aura:attribute name="jsObj" type="Object" default="{aValue: 5}"/>` or another?

Comment: whats your use case for using type "object" , you can accomplish most use cases using built in aura attribute types

Comment: I have a tooltip on hovering in one component. I have another component in which a user can change the text displayed in the tooltip by typing his/her own text in the input field. For the visualization I am using `svg` `d3.js`. So, what I would like to do now is to pass a JavaScript `svg` object with a reference to a tooltip object to the component in which the user can change the text of the tooltip. And then when the user changes the text I would update it using the reference passed. it is the best communication I was able to come up with between components in the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Kris Gray ([@GrayJustise](https://twitter.com/GrayJustise)) pointed out on Twitter once, Object is a simple Object, and Lightning doesn't know what to do with it, so it does this only safe thing it can: it makes it a String. Instead, use a Map, which tells Lightning that you have a key-value pair in there you're trying to parse:

```
<aura:attribute name="jsObj" type="Map" default="{'aValue': 5}"/>
```

Note that you should be using JSON-like syntax (e.g. quoting strings, etc). Lightning will try to do the right thing if you specify Map, but most likely will not if you specify Object. Note that this *only* applies to the `default` attribute. If you are setting the attribute inside of a method (via component.set), it doesn't matter which you use:

```
<aura:attribute name="jsObj" type="Object" />

init: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.jsObj", { aValue: 5 });
}
```